# How to perform AND operation in SNS filtering on same message attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, filtering, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Source publishing on SNS topic with the following message attribute.

```
{"messageAttributes": {"validSet":["a","b"]}}
```

Now one SQS is subscribed to this SNS topic. I want to associate SNS filtering with this subscription. I tried with the following SNS filtering.

```
{"validSet":["a","b"]}
```

But in this case it sends the message to SQS even when it receives message with only parameter "a" or "b".

I want to enforce the rule that when this set contains both "a" and "b" then only forward the message to SQS.

Comment: The current AND/OR logic in SNS filtering is pretty limited. You can AND multiple attributes, and you can OR multiple values for an attribute. I believe the only way to achieve what you're looking for is to have multiple attributes, one for "a" and one for "b".

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I cannot take it as multiple attribute because this can cross the no. of message attribute limit of SNS which is equal to 10 I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn’t really an option at this time, to the best of my knowledge. You’ll have to do the filtering in your code. So filter it down to “a” or “b” and in your code ignore it unless it has both.

Comment: Alright @JasonWadsworth. Thanks for confirming this behaviour.